# Kentico build error

Tags: kentico

I'm getting an error when i build the site, "The name 'CMSPortalManager1' does not exists.

This is in my globalMaster.master page, which i was working on. All i did was change the path of the favicon.ico. I did a compare with my previous version and nothing but the icon path has been changed.

The error seems to be from here:

```html
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcManagers">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="manScript" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
          ScriptMode="Release" />
        <cms:CMSPortalManager ID="CMSPortalManager1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I've done build before, but nothing in the last few days. All my work has been in the CMSDesk, or SASS/JS work.

Also, this Master page has a child Master, but i don't see any errors there. Where should i start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: i just rolled back and the error is gone. So i'll make my small change and see if it dies,.

Comment: it's all good.I think me reorganzing the media library was the issues. I love it when it works, but when it doesn't....